# Blender keeps crashing when opening a file

Tags: rendering

So: I dont know anythig about Blender but my friend does and i have a fairly good computer while he has a crappy one. So he wanted to send me files to render (.blend). Everytime when i try to open them Blender crashes instantly. I tried opening them on different ways and i installed older versions of Blender and installed Blender in different folders and nothing works for me.
Do you have any ideas what we can do?

Comment: Which version of blender does your friend used to do the work?

Comment: And secondly, is it opening on your friend system?